# Flask - Take URL in Route?

Tags: python, flask, router

I have a question about Flask.

I want to use one endpoint to handle requests.

To do so, I need to take url in router like:

```
@app.route("/<url>", methods=['GET','POST'])
def home(url):
    base_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/"
    my_url = base_url + url
```

For example, I will sent request to my Flask app as " localhost:5000/api/v3/files/samehashvalue "
and it will combine it with virustotal url.

my_url will something like = virustotal.com/api/v3/files/samehashvalue

How can I pass /api/v3... to my router? Without using parameters like ?url=...

Comment: you can define routes like, if thats what you ask. `app.route('/api/v3/et/cetera')`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading [redirects](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) from the Flask docs as well as [url building](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors).

With your specific example you can obtain the url from the route and pass it into your Flask function.  It's then just a case of using redirect and an f string to redirect to that new url.

```
# http://localhost:5000/test redirects to 
# https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files/test


from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def url_redirector(path):
    return redirect(f'https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files/{path}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: sorry but /api/v3/files/ is not fixed url it can be like /api/v3/urls etc. so it varies. how can i handle it like dynamic route?

Comment: Try now.. remember though that path:path matches everything so if you redirect to localhost:5000 it will catch that and end up being a recursive and break :-)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is correct, but I assume that you can specify the path in @app.route if it is a fixed path. For example:

```
@app.route("/api/v3/files", methods=['GET','POST'])
def home(url):
    base_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files/"
```

Then the hash value only can be passed as a parameter.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question and I will edit this answer.

Comment: sorry but path is not fixed and it varies. sometimes it will be /api/v3/files, or /api/v3/urls etc. also /api/v3 can be changed to v4 in future. so i want use one router and take url (/api/v3...) and combine it to virustotal.com/